# jQuery Datatables no result but still showing pagination

Tags: jquery, pagination, datatables

I have code like this for Datatables:

```
var table = $('#req-non-purr');
    var filter = $('.form-filter');
    var target = table.attr('data-table');
    var tblDetail = table.attr('data-detail');
    var oTable = table.on( 'processing.dt', function ( e, settings, processing ) {
            if (processing) {
                $(this).find('tbody').addClass('load1 csspinner');
            } else{
                $(this).find('tbody').removeClass('load1 csspinner');
            };
        } ).DataTable({
            "ajax": host+'datatable/'+target,
            "bProcessing": true,
            "iDisplayRecords" : 5,
            "pagingType": "full_numbers",
            "bServerSide": true,
            "columnDefs": [{
                "targets": [ 0 ],
                "className": "details-control",
            }]
        });

    $('.btn-form-filter').click(function(){
        var arr = formFilter(filter);
        oTable.ajax.url( host+'datatables/'+target+'?filter='+arr ).load();
        return false;
    });
```

It works if I push the button; it will show data from AJAX, but my problem is even there's no result, or it has a result more than 10, or more my pagination not working at all.  For example : Datatable has no result but my pagination still showing 1 until 5 page `{data: []}` but when result more then 10 my Datatable is overload so I'm stuck on row 6 (can't scroll down more). I just put `"iDisplayRecords" : 5,` but it is not working at all.

Can anyone help me?

EDIT : Sorry to all, i'm found my problem, the problem is not in jquery or json, but on my php database.php, i'm put my josn inside looping. Now my problem is, i just put `"iDisplayRecords" : 5,` but my datatables still show 10 row/page. Any help??

Comment: add working fiddle or SO may be?

Comment: Using the console, what does your AJAX returned look like?  Is it JSON?  You haven't defined it properly... you need an object defined in the `ajax` parameter, which should include a `url`, `type`, `data` etc...

Comment: @Sablefoste i'm using json.

Comment: You need to tell Datatables where to put the incoming JSON.  I recommend you study this: https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax

Comment: @Sablefoste : I'm sorry and i found my problem, well my fault is on php i was looping while i'm using json.

Comment: I'm glad you figured it out.  To answer your other question, the `iDisplayRecords` will only return information for the Datables footer.  If your JSON returns 10 records, it will show 10 records.

Comment: @Sablefoste : owww... Tq, i kinda forgot about that xD